# grep not matching lines containing a question mark

Tags: grep

I want to get the names of all services that are currently running by using

```
sudo service --status-all | grep -E '[A-Za-z0-9-]+$'
```

Which to me seems like it should select the correct substrings from the output, but for some reason all lines starting with

```
[ ? ]
```

are not matched?

Comment: Can you give an example of such a (non-matched) line? What happens if you modify your pattern to include optional whitespace at the end of the line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that those with the `[ ? ]` are on stderr rather than stdout so grep can't see them use `|&` to grep both pipes see example below:

```
service --status-all |& grep -E '[A-Za-z0-9\.-]+$'
```

Note that I've also changed your regex slightly with `\.` because services like `rc.local` won't be picked up by your original one.

Comment: Or `service --status-all 2>&1 | grep -E '[A-Za-z0-9-]+$'`.